# WooCommerce: Get the post id in javascript code and pass it through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help figuring out how to get the product id from the product page, to my function that opens a model box after a vimeo video ends.
inside that model box i need a variable with the product id. so i automatic can get the price of the product and insert the id inside a shortcode.

Hopefully someone can help, and feel free to ask, i will try to help if you need more information.

I have already tried the most common ideas, i could find.

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
```

or

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID
```

or

```
global $product;
$id = $product->id;
```

I have tried in all the variations i could find.

if i use the first one, my function wont even work.

If i use the other 2, it only gives me a 0 as value.

```
// The javascript to call the function when video ends.
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on("ended", function() {
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'runThisPhpFunction',
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(popupfunction) {
        $("#popup-box").html(popupfunction);
    });
  });
});
```

Next up is my function.

```
//Call Javascript video vimeo script to functions

function add_my_scripts() {

        global $product;
        $deps = array('jquery');
        $in_footer = true;

            wp_register_script( 'myjavascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myjavascript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
          wp_enqueue_script( 'myjavascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myjavascript.js');
  }


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts' );

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_runThisPhpFunction', 'runThisPhpFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_runThisPhpFunction', 'runThisPhpFunction' );

global $wpdb;
global $wp;

// THE FUNCTION WHERE I NEED THE ID FROM CURRENT PRODUCT PAGE AUTOMATIC

function runThisPhpFunction() {
  global $product;
  $product = wc_get_product();
  $siteid = $product->ID;

    //echo '<script>console.log($product);</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("popup-box").classList.remove("hidden");</script>';
    echo '<div class="modalheader">';
    echo '<h3>Undskyld. Vi stoppede videoen!</h3>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="modalcontent">';
    echo $siteid, 'Men vi venter lige her, klar til at fortsætte når du har hentet Dankortet ';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something but I don't see any ID being set/passed in the JavaScript code that makes the Ajax call.

Comment: Well that is because i dont know how i would do that :)

Comment: This won't format correctly in a comment but this is what I use with jQuery to call PHP using Ajax `var request = $.ajax({
  url: 'http://yoururl.example.com/runThisPhpFunction.php',
  data: { look4 : request.term } ,
  dataType: "text",
  cache: false
  })`.

Comment: In your case the `look4` in my example would be `id` and the value needs to match your HTML field name. You can't call a PHP function directly, you need to call a PHP script and return a value.

Comment: And what does that one do, dave it is confusing me a bit, and am i supposed to paste it into functions.php or in my JS File :)

Comment: That's JavaScript of course.

Comment: Cool, But runThisPhpFunction is a function i made inside function.php - so is this still gonna work? :)

Comment: As I said above, you can't run a function directly, you need to make that function a standalone PHP file or modify your `function.php` to accept some sort of parameter that you can pass to have it run a specific function.

Comment: The function as it is now is executing just fine, i just need to find the id of the product as i describe in the top :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using javascript/jQuery/Ajax and as you need to get the product ID *(which is the Post ID)* in your Javascript code to pass it through Ajax to PHP, try the following revisited code instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_vimeo_player_script' );
function custom_vimeo_player_script() {
    // Not in cart, checkout and my account pages
    if( ! ( is_checkout() || is_cart() || is_account_page() ) ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        if (typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined') 
            return false;

        var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe"),
            player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

        player.on('ended', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'enable_vimeo_popup_box',
                    'the_id': <?php echo get_the_id(); ?>,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // if popup-box has the class hidden
                    if( $("#popup-box").hasClass('hidden') && result ){
                        // remove the class hidden and add the html output
                        $("#popup-box").removeClass('hidden').html(result);
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                },
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// PHP: WordPress Ajax function triggered by Javascript
add_action( 'wp_ajax_enable_vimeo_popup_box', 'enable_vimeo_popup_box' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_enable_vimeo_popup_box', 'enable_vimeo_popup_box' );
function enable_vimeo_popup_box() {
    if( isset($_POST['the_id']) ){
        $post_id = (int) $_POST['the_id'];

        echo '<div class="modalheader">
        <h3>' . __("Undskyld. Vi stoppede videoen!") . '</h3>
        </div><div class="modalcontent">' .
        '<em>(post_id er ' . $post_id . ')</em> ' .
        __("Men vi venter lige her, klar til at fortsætte når du har hentet Dankortet ") .
        '</div>';
    }
    die();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: This works Perfektly! - Now i just have one more question :)
How would i put it inside my shortcode 
        echo do_shortcode('[product price="$post_id"]'); 

Because as i put it above here, it picks the wrong product.

Comment: @FizzelTV Could you add in your question as an edit at the end, your actual shortcode code… Thank you… Once done notify me here please.

Comment: I figured it out myself, i put in the wrong shortcode, and forgot to do the ' . . ' Next to $post_id :) - You have been my savior the last few days :D